# Create simple selector functions with redux-toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

Is there a way to create the simple selector functions automatically when I use the `createSlice` function from the [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `createSlice` does not currently generate any selector functions for you.  (We did originally have a "slice selector" that was generated, but [we removed that in v0.7.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v0.7.0) as it wasn't actually useful for anything.)

You should call import and call `createSelector` yourself as appropriate.  See these Redux docs pages for more info on using `createSelector` to create memoized selectors:

- ["Redux Essentials" tutorial, Part 6: Performance and Normalization](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization)
- ["Redux Fundamentals" tutorial, Part 7: Standard Redux Patterns](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#memoized-selectors)
- [Redux Usage Guides: Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors)

Comment: Sadly, the intermediate tutorial has been deprecated. From what I understand, it is still available [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/e85eb17b39a2118d859f7b7746e0f3fee523e089/docs/tutorials/intermediate-tutorial.md). The relevant up-to-date documentation page is [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) now, but it only has partial examples.

Comment: Edited the comment to point to our current docs on using selectors